# How to correctly discard result of a (monadic) computation in F#

Tags: haskell, f#, monads, computation-expression, do-notation

In Haskell, I can write:

```
token: Parser a -> Parser a
token p = do space
             v <- p
             space  
             return v
```

In F#, I have come this far:

```
let token = compose {
        let! _ = space
        let! v = parser
        let! _ = space
        return v
    }
```

In other words, I have to introduce this unused `let! _ =` binding to discard the parse value of "space" parser (monad), that I don't need.

How to avoid these useless bindings in F#? I have tried using do!, but I get an error (because my `>>=` function does not take type unit but 'a):

```
let (>>=) (p: Parser<'a>) (f: 'a -> Parser<'b>) : Parser<'b>
```

Here is my builder definition:

```
type ParserComposer() = 
  member x.Bind(p, f) = p >>= f
  member x.Return(y) = ret y
  member x.Zero() = failure
```

Do I need to define `>>` function? Add Combine() to builder? Any ideas how to do this right? Code example?

Comment: You can define `>>` but with a different name as it's already a standard operator. Example: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/9ad7ff3024b1cc90fd252520272421920c1f4017/src/FSharpx.Core/ComputationExpressions/Monad.fs#L779

Comment: Ok, and when I have defined >> under a different name, what do I do?

Comment: You use it just as you would in Haskell. Or use `let! _ = ...`

Comment: But this is exactly what I am trying to avoid, this unnecessary binding.

Is there a keyword that will use this >> or Combine, like !let is using >>= ?
It seems like there is some syntax " ; " for Combine, but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Either define `>>.`, use `let! _ = ...` , or `map ignore` it. Those are your options.

Comment: You'd have similar issues in Haskell, with the compiler giving you *Warning: A do-notation statement discarded a result of type Foo*. The only solution I can think of is to use parser combinators in Applicative style.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the return type of `space` is `Parser<unit>` (which would make sense if it does not represent a parser that returns some result) you can write:

```
let token = compose {
    do! space
    let! v = parser
    do! space
    return v
}
```

This is just a syntactic sugar for what you wrote - so `do! e` is translated as `let! _ = e` which is, in turn, translated to `parser.Bind(e, fun _ -> ...)`. I have a sample for [Additive parsers on Try Joinads](http://tryjoinads.org/computations/) which also defines `Combine` and a few more (possibly) useful things, but the `do!` keyword only needs `Bind`.

Comment: Ok, in this case space is a Parser<unit>, so I can use "do!". But what if it is a parser of something else? In many cases it does return something useful, but I just don't need it. 
In Haskell I simply don't bind it in this case. What is the best way to handle it in F#? Is Combine something I should use then?

Comment: @badbadboy: Even in that case you can use `do!` as the `Bind` documentation in Computation expression says `Called for let! and do! in computation expressions`

Comment: Yes, but then I get a compilation error because do! calls Bind supplying it with (), while it expects different type ('a).
@tomas-petricek, any suggestions?